# Refresh/Reset StreamProvider - Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-provider

In my app, I have the following providers.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport.global(
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [userLoggedIn, currentUserData],
        child: MaterialApp(...)))
}
```

```dart
  var userLoggedIn = StreamProvider<User?>.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(), initialData: null);

  var currentUserData = StreamProvider<FrediUser>.value(
    updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,
    initialData: FrediUser(
      loginProvider: '',
      email: '',
      admin: false,
        profileSettings: [],
        profileChips: [],
        profileStats: [],
        id: 'loading',
        imageUrl: 'loading',
        bio: 'loading',
        username: 'loading'),
    value: currentUserID != null ? currentUserDataStream() : null,
  );
```

### PROBLEM

When the user logs out (or logs in for the first time), the provider is either:

- Containing old user data (until a hot restart is done, when the providers are called again and reloaded)
- Null or empty, because there was no user before.

**What I want to do is to** refresh or call the `Stream Providers` again once I have a new user, or delete all the data once a user logs off.

Thank you!

Comment: looks like you're not updating your `currentUserData` provider?

Comment: @MinjinGelegdorj that is precisely the problem I want to resolve

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the changes of auth state like this.

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Although this is not merely what I was looking for, It sparked an idea. I will be posting the answer soon.

Comment: @TomasWard Have you been able to figure this out? I am having a similar challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing a similar problem as you are, I've come up with a work-around although not sure how "valid" it is according to the `Provider` architecture

## The Problem

I've got a `DatabaseService` class which has a stream function of type `Stream<CustomUser>` function, and I used it like this:

```
//--- main.dart ---//

runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
      // ..some other providers.. //

        // data provider
        Provider<DatabaseService?>(
          create: (_) => databaseService,
        ),

        // data provider
        StreamProvider<CustomUser?>(
          create: (context) => databaseService.getCurrUserFromDb(),
          lazy: false,
          initialData: null,
          updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,
        ),

      ],
      child: MyApp(
        initPage: initPage,
      )
));
```

Stream Function:

```
//--- database_service.dart ---//

  // gets the user from database and
  // assigns it to the variable _user.
  Stream<CustomUser?> getCurrUserFromDB() async* {
    try {
      CustomUser? currUser;

      if (_user != null) {
        await for (DocumentSnapshot<Object?> event
            in users.doc(user.uid).snapshots()) {
          final jsonMap = event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          currUser = CustomUser.fromJson(jsonMap);
          _user = currUser;
          CustomPreferences.setCurrUser(_user);
          yield currUser;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

***databaseService** is the DatabaseService class with named constructors.*

This was ***not*** causing the widgets to rebuild at the start nor when the stream has a new value

## Solution:

Created a `StreamController` in the `DatabaseService` class, and when the user signs in I add the stream function:`getCurrUserFromDB()`  to the `StreamController` like this

```
//--- authentication_screen.dart ---//

...
ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text("Sign In"),
    onPressed: () async {
      final user = await AuthService().googleSignIn();
      if (user != null) {
        final dbProvider = context.read<DatabaseService?>();
        await dbProvider?.setInitUser(user, context);
        await dbProvider?.cusUserController
            .addStream(dbProvider.getCurrUserFromDB());
      }
    }),
...
```

`setInitUser(CustomUser? user)` is used set the value of the `_user` variable in `DatabaseService` and `user` is used to get this variable.

## Reasoning

I am ***creating*** a `StreamProvider` at the start of the app, and its source the `StreamController` needs to have a stream to listen so I give it when I am trying to sign in.

Or even cleaner solution would be to do it in the constructor of `DatabaseService` Class like this:

```
//--- database_service.dart ---//

// method to add the stream to controller //
Future<void> addStream() async {
    if (!_cusUserController.isClosed && !_cusUserController.isPaused) {
      await _cusUserController.addStream(getCurrUserFromDB());
    }
  }

// constructor //
DatabaseService._init(CustomUser cusUser) {
    addStream();
    _user = cusUser;
  }
```

And one last thing to note is that I don't make the declare the Controller as final. When I had it declared as final the streams weren't updating, so it looks like this now:

```
//--- database_service.dart ---//

    StreamController<CustomUser?> _cusUserController = StreamController();
```

## TL;DR

I created a `StreamProvider` which returns a `StreamController` in its create property and later down the life cycle of the app I gave the controller a Stream using the addStream method.

Sorry for the wall of text I just wanted to come out as clear as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Although it seems complicated and hard to scale, it has given me an idea on what to do. I will be posting the answer in some days for you to see too. @Daniel Chettiar I will give you the bounty for your efforts.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, streams do seem to be a tricky part in flutter to tackle , I am working on this a little more as well. I will update this answer if I find a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DanielChettiar Any chance you've figured out a better solution?

Comment: @Igbokwenu I agree this solution isn't nearly neat or workable for everyone. I don't have the project right now, but I can try rebuilding this with a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Igbokwenu Hey, I've added a shorter to-the-point answer, hopefully you may find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to control when the `StreamProvider` can rebuild. You can try is using a `Stream` from a `StreamController` rather than a `Function` that returns a stream.

Using a `StreamController` allows you to add values to its stream using:
`streamController.sink.add(event);`. Doing this will ***refresh*** the stream which will allow you to update your UI.

I am using Firebase for this example so the code snippets may consist some `FirebaseAuth` methods.

---

#### Solution

###### I made a class for handling Authentication called `auth_helper.dart`.

```
class AuthHelper {

  // Creating a StreamController that has a Stream which will return the `User?`
  static final StreamController<User?> currUserController =
      StreamController<User?>();

  // This function is called in the main method to make sure the stream of my
  // stream controller starts listening to the changes when the auth state changes
  static init() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
      currUserController.sink.add(event);
    });
  }

  // This is an optional method that you can use to add a User object programmatically
  // This value can be null.
  static clearUserProgrammatically({User? user}) {
    if (!currUserController.isClosed && !currUserController.isPaused) {
      currUserController.sink.add(user);
    }
  }
}
```

###### I am calling this function in my `main.dart`

Calling it before `runApp()` so that my `currUserController` starts listening to the Auth changes right after Firebase has been initialized.

```
  // Firebase Initialization, etc.,
  AuthHelper.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
```

###### The `MultiProvider` will look something like this now

```
MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      StreamProvider(
          // passing the stream of currUserController instead of 
          // `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`
          create: (_) => AuthHelper.currUserController.stream,
          initialData: null)
      ],
...
)
```

###### Lastly this is how you can manually/programmatically update the stream

```
ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text('Clean up provider by code'),
    onPressed: () async {
        AuthHelper.clearUserProgrammatically(null);
    },
),
```

[source code](https://github.com/1MochaChan1/streamprovider-refresh-so)

Comment: I am currently trying to implement this and while it is still giving me a lot of challenges, I really do appreciate the time and effort it took to put this together.

Comment: @Igbokwenu No worries, if you need help with any of those challenges, let me know.